# Printing all permutations of the upcased of a lower cased string

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I am trying to print out all of the upcased version permutation of a lower cased string in Ruby.  For ex:

original string: aaa,

output is:

aaa
aaA
aAa
aAA
Aaa
AaA
AAa
AAA

Any help or hints is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show us code you've written to solve this. It's a lot easier to fix your mistakes, than it is for us to write multiple versions and you to shoehorn them into place.

Answer (score 3):

```
str = 'aaa'

(0...1<<str.length).map { |i|
    str.chars.map.with_index { |a,b| ((i>>b)&1).zero? ? a : a.upcase }.join
}

# => aaa Aaa aAa AAa aaA AaA aAA AAA
```

Basic idea is that there are going to be 2 to the power of `n` (`2**n == 1<<n`) output strings, where `n=str.length`. Therefore you can use an index `i` from 0 to `2**n-1` as a bitfield for which letters are going to be upcased. E.g.

```
000 -> aaa
001 -> aaA
010 -> aAa
011 -> aAA
etc.
```

Comment: Matt, `(0...1<<str.length)` is very cool!  I'll try to remember that for combinatorial problems.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`repeated_permutation`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/repeated_permutation) to do what you want:

```
%w(a A).repeated_permutation(3).map(&:join)
# => ["aaa", "aaA", "aAa", "aAA", "Aaa", "AaA", "AAa", "AAA"]
```

for an arbitrary string, you can create permutations of the question whether to upcase the letter or not, something like:

```
str = 'abcde'
chars = str.chars

[false, true].repeated_permutation(str.length).map do |permutation|
  chars.zip(permutation).map do |char, upcase|
    upcase ? char.upcase : char
  end.join
end

# => ["abcde", "abcdE", "abcDe", "abcDE", "abCde", "abCdE", "abCDe", "abCDE", 
#     "aBcde", "aBcdE", "aBcDe", "aBcDE", "aBCde", "aBCdE", "aBCDe", "aBCDE",
#     "Abcde", "AbcdE", "AbcDe", "AbcDE", "AbCde", "AbCdE", "AbCDe", "AbCDE",
#     "ABcde", "ABcdE", "ABcDe", "ABcDE", "ABCde", "ABCdE", "ABCDe", "ABCDE"]
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer @Uri's solution for the specific case, but would suggest this for the arbitrary strings of lowercase letters:

```
str = "abad"

arr = str.chars.map { |c| [c,c.upcase] }
arr.shift.product(*arr).map(&:join)
  #=> ["abad", "abaD", "abAd", "abAD", "aBad", "aBaD", "aBAd", "aBAD",
  #    "Abad", "AbaD", "AbAd", "AbAD", "ABad", "ABaD", "ABAd", "ABAD"]
```

Comment: @Casimar (aka regex guru?), I tried that, but couldn't bear to see code so cramped.

Comment: Don't tell it to anyone, but I feel totally overwhelmed on this site!